# How to check if Azure public IP is 'associated' via Python SDK

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-python-sdk, azure-public-ip

I am trying to get a list of Public IP addresses that are not associated to any azure resource. That is 'orphaned public ip addresses'. I want to know if Azure public IP is 'associated' via Python SDK.

Using the below SDK:

```
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
public_ip_list = network_client.public_ip_addresses.list_all()
```

Iterating over 'public_ip_list' will give me all the details regarding IP, but it wont say if it is 'associated' with any azure resource or not.

Comment: You can use the "network_client.public_ip_addresses.list_all()" method and filter the results based on the "ip_tags" property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get a list of Public IP addresses that are not associated with any Azure resource

You can use the below to get both associated and non-associated Public IPs with Azure service using Azure python sdk.

You can get the public IP that is not associated with Azure resource when you set ip_config to none and also you can get the count of both associated and non-associated IP.

**Code:**

```
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
Subscription_id="your-subscription-id"
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential,Subscription_id)

public_ip_list = network_client.public_ip_addresses.list_all()
associated_count = 0
non_associated_count=0
for public_ip in public_ip_list:
    if public_ip.ip_configuration is None:
        non_associated_count+=1
        print(f"Public IP address {public_ip.name} is not associated with any Azure resource.")
    else:
        associated_count += 1
        print(f"Public IP address {public_ip.name} is associated with Azure resource {public_ip.ip_configuration.id}.")
print("Count of Non-associated with resource:",non_associated_count)
print("Count of associated with resource:",associated_count)
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Public IP address xxxxxxx is associated with Azure resource /subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/xxxx/ipConfigurations/primary.
Public IP address xx is not associated with any Azure resource.
Count of Non-associated with resource: 26
Count of associated with resource: 79
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Public IP Addresses - List All - REST API (Azure Virtual Networks) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/public-ip-addresses/list-all?tabs=Python#list-all-public-ip-addresses)